# F#: Converting FSharpRef to C# object reference

Tags: c#, f#, ref

I use my F# Class Library in another C# project. The function I am calling returns an object like this:

```
type Item =
{ Title: string
  Items: List<Item ref> }
```

The problem is that I when using it in C#, the `Items` property is of type `List<FSharpRef<Item>>`.
So the question is:

How can I convert it to `List<Item>` (in F#) without loosing the references to objects?

i.e. in cases when two `Item` objects have a reference to a third one inside their lists, they should refer to the same object in C#.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to explain why you're using `ref`s in the first place in the F# code.

Comment: @kvb Basically, the 'Item' type has a structure of a one-directional graph, where two or more nodes may point to the same node.

Comment: But you don't need ref for that...  Items are already reference types from the .NET type system perspective.

Comment: @kvb That is a good point! But, that works only if the object is immutable, right?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to mutate; you could mark the fields as `mutable` to mutate them, but that is different from what you have now (right now you can alter individual elements of the `Items` list, but not, say, the length of the list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who participated in the discussion! The following solutions have emerged:

1. Dereference the values in C# (by creating some kind of a `flatMap`);
2. Just not use `ref` at all - works fine if the values should be immutable;
3. Use `ref` inside F#, but return an object of another type which doesn't require `ref`.

I've used the third strategy, since I needed to transform the objects to the other type anyways.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the items to still be inside ref cells in C# then you can keep the F# as it is and dereference each `FSharpRef` in C# just before using it with its `.Value` property.

Comment: That's an option, but the F# library is used by other team members and they would rather like to have to use it without any additional steps. It's also an option to declare the Item class inside C# (I guess, that should work), but it also involves external (non-F#) code. I thought there's some standard way of doing it, but, I guess, using F# inside .NET projects is just not really popular.

Comment: I'm not completely sure how making `Item` a C# class helps, but it's likely that you can produce the same class from F# too instead of using a record.